# Application jar not getting loaded in Izpack

Tags: izpack

I am using Izpack 5. I have added myapplication.jar in the install.xml as follows:

```
<packs>
 <pack name="Core" required="yes">
   <description>Core Installation Files</description>
   <file src="myapplication.jar" targetdir="/Users/manjirilakhote/Izpack/extract" override="true"  unpack="true" />
 </pack>
</packs>
```

After compiling the xml, it shows in the logs that the file has been extracted and added at the target location. But it does not appear physically at that location. Hence the actual application is not installed.
Am I missing any configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Your `targetdir` is most likely the culprit here. Make sure that:

- the path you reference really exists (for instance on Linux systems there is no `/Users` folder),
- or that you have the correct permissions to write to it (not all higher-level folders under `/` have rwx permissions for the regular user),
- and finally that your installer is run with the necessary privileges.

Don't forget that **IzPack** does not always tell you if something went wrong: it is known that its logs may be misleading in some situations.